# Can't find content of div elements in BeautifulSoup code

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to get the links from these Match Pages with BeautifulSoup from the official website of UEFA (fig 1).

[image: Fig 1]

The picture above is just one `<div class="mdsession matchBox innGrid_8 forappnode">` of those 2 shown in the picture below (fig 2). The only elements I can get are the `<h3>` tags while the links are somewhere in the `<table>` tags which don't appear in BeautifulSoup ( fig 3)

[image: Fig 2]

[image: Fig 3]

Any help would be much appreciated as I really need it for my final year project. Thank you

Comment: Send the link. Or use inspect on chrome to find out. I went to a link that looks like yours - http://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/season=2018/matches/#md/33348
Over there, you need to traverse to div class='match-list' and then class='match-row' and then <a> tag.

Comment: Ask a question,  and post your code (minimal example) so we can see what's going wrong.

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to add the link. here you go: http://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/season=2017/matches/round=2000782/index.html

Comment: I have put my code in the command line, I hope that's enough

Comment: It's generated by js, you may have to use `selenium`.

Comment: Or you can use this url: http://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/season=2017/matches/library/fixtures/day=-2/session=1/_matchesbydate.html?_=1507804262056

Comment: your request only shows the content of all the <div class="mdsession matchBox innGrid_8 forappnode">There is 2 and each of them contain <h3> and 2 <div>. So you need to look further in the <div> that start with "session" to access your <table>.

Comment: @t.m.adam How did you find this link?

Comment: Click Inspect > Network > XHR. Very helpful tool for web scraping.